# Dynamic Time Warping w/ Different Sampling Rates

Tags: time-series, clustering, dynamic-time-warping

I am fairly familiar with the basics of calculating the Dynamic Time Warping distance between two time series but I am not sure if it can handle the following case:

- Two series sampled at different and irregular rates.

For example, I observe how many leaves fall from two different trees and I record the the time that each leaf or set of leaves fall. So observations for tree 1 might look like, at (10AM,1), (10:00:01,5), (10:00:08,2), etc. Then tree 2 might be (10AM,0), (10:00:03,1), (10:00:12,1), etc.

How can I apply DTW in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't do that. One of the primary assumptions of using DTW is that each signal is sampled at a constant sampling rate. The original paper also states that the sampling rate should be common to each other. I can invisage a change to the original code that could be made to account for a different sampling rate in each, however a non-constant sampling rate would be very difficult, if not impossible. The original paper can be found here https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1163055 (Sakoe, H., and Chiba, S., 1978).

Perhaps you could alter the data in your example before hand to be a cumulitive sum of the number of leaves that have fallen for each tree, then you could sample that at a regular interval common to both data sets. I think the DTW algorithm would be able to work as-is for that without changing the algorithm.